# Changing Look & Fell of Liferay Portal Project

Tags: portlet, tomcat7, portal, liferay-6

I want to ask for changing look and feel for my portal project. For example main page...

I have html, css, and javascript. I read many documents about hooks project from Liferay site(and also pdf docs), but I could't reach any solution.

I don't want to change any portlet, I want to change interface of my portal sites.

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the overrall look and feel of the project using Themes. Themes are like skin which you can apply across a set of pages or just a single page. Check the following link to create the theme

[How to create a theme](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-5)

Comment: I created themes project,and I changed background, fonts... but I want to change div tags, and their places. Because, I need to implement my website to a liferay portal project.

Comment: Yes you need to map your websites structure with theme. Use the velocity file in the theme to create the structure. Like everything related to navigation is in navigation.vm. About that there is header and then actual portlet content  then the footer. You can create your own divs to organize the structure in portal_normal.vm. If it is the way the portlets are arranged in portal body, then you have to create Layout Templates.

Comment: I understand with your words that, you want me to go with a Themes project. I also found a link; http://www.oshyn.com/BlogRetrieve.aspx?BlogID=1907&PostID=63328%20. I think think this will be helpful.

Comment: Hi sandeepnair85, I tried to follow that link but it is an advanced entry. I am a little bit new to Liferay. Could you please write the steps. Because I don't know how to change .vm files.

Comment: Yes for that you need to know Velocity. http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html  Theme in liferay consist of vm(velocity files that allows to create a template of you whole website), images , css and js. All these files have to overriden in diffs folder. The link that I gave above  for theme has all the information. But first you need to go through the velocity guide, the link of which I have shared in this post. Its quite easy to understand once you read the user guide.

Comment: I started reading, thank you very much, I will share the result :)

Comment: Hi sandeepnair85. I created a Theme project. I mapped folders from classic Theme folder to my Theme project(with copy-paste). I have css,images,js,and templates folders in _diffs folder, in my project. I found all .vm files in the templates folder. That is great. There are divs as you said. Thank you very much.